# Swift dyld: Library not loaded - using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I apologize for what may seem like an overly asked question, but no matter how many answers to related questions I'm asking, none of them seem to work. See (in order) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909870/xcode-6-and-embedded-frameworks-only-supported-in-ios8), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126835/swift-framework-depending-on-cocoa-pod), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found).

I'm running Xcode 6.4 with iOS 8 (iPhone only), using CocoaPods. Many of other answers provided, there seems to be a build setting, or general setting that does not exist in my version of Xcode, yielding many conclusions not helpful.

As a matter of reference, I followed [This CocoaPods Tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/cocoapods-tutorial-ios8-swift?rq=pods) which worked with ease. But it's only when I attempt to load the app onto my phone (yes, I have valid certificates, and my other apps work just fine without using other dependencies), the app immediately crashes just as it's about to load.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Pods_ExamplePods.framework/Pods_ExamplePods
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F109A377-3EA4-48C2-9042-CB6C384C9F30/ExamplePods.app/ExamplePods
Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

See here where I named my app "ExamplePods"

[image]

And then here is my Folder Structure, opened in Workspace mode. Note that there's only 3 dependencies.

[image]

Then see "General Settings" and "Build Settings"

[image]

[image]

I'm at a complete loss, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I see you're also getting a warning. Is the warning something like this?

> ld: warning: -weak_framework is treated as -framework when used with -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES). Weak linking may still happen based on availability mark-up in headers

If so you should try to keep the framework weak linked and disable bitcode..

Found this screenshot here.
[image]

If that doesn't work try disabling anything else you didn't compile with. Checking for pods update etc.

Comment: Can you link the screenshot to the original answer?

Comment: You should not disable bitcode on app target because it is necessary to improve performance

Answer (score 1):

It is a known cocoa pods issue. See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3903

You can either downgrade cocoa pods. Or using the methods mentioned the that post: delete "Compatibility version" completely, leave it empty.
A simple script can be added to Podfile to automate this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['DYLIB_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION'] = ''
    end
  end
end
```

Then clean your project and run pod install.

Comment: That looks like a different issue - that's a fix for an incompatible library version, and this is about a missing binary image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I embed frameworks and also use CocoaPods.

The following steps fixes it for me:

1. Go to Target's Build Phases
2. Move the "Embed Frameworks" phase below "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks" and "[CP] Copy Pods Resources" phases.

Hope it helps others who come across this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and following solution solved it.

In Linked Frameworks and Libraries (in Build Phases), mark Pods.framework to Optional instead of required.