# Cocoapods shell script invocation error

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, ios8, cocoapods

Trying to build an iOS 8 app. But encountering an error with cocoapods which titles **"Run custom shell script 'Embed Pods Frameworks'"**.

I'm using iOS 8 as deployment target and XCode 6.3.

I tried many solutions out there. But they are not working. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Removed 'Embed Pods Framework' and adding copy files phase. Compile succeeded doing that. But app not installs in the simulator. Xcode gives an error with "Launching services error"

[image]

Comment: i this possibly an issue: https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot/issues/87 or are you using this POD?

Comment: I don't use snapshot into my project.

Comment: let me build a new prog with swift and alamofire, one sec

Comment: Okay so this worked for me, Dinesh

Comment: How far along are you in this project? Did you just start it or are you WAY deep into it?

Comment: I'll just tell you the difference, here's my pod file, I'd suggest you delete your entire pods' project and reinstall it, using this:   # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'yourProjectName' do
pod 'Alamofire'
end

Comment: Yes. cocoapods working with other projects. Simply this one. I have finished a version 1.

Comment: I suspect this could be a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29463810/1083859 I'm also seeing that pods.framework is not created and it is showing in red color only for this project. I already tried deleting the entire pods and reinstalled it. Same result

Comment: Yep, try to reinstall the Alamofire POD but in your pod file, right before you declare any "pod xxx" just write, "use_frameworks!"

Comment: HA!, that would solve it if that answer there is the answer, must easier!

Comment: Compile succeeded doing that. But app not installs in the simulator. Xcode gives an error with "Launching services error"

Comment: Yep, let me try this Dinesh

Comment: I hope it happens only after I updated cocoa pods. But still I'm seeing pods.framework in red color which means file not found.

Comment: What about this, Dinesh?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130558/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-an-error-was-encountered-while-running-domain

Comment: And, what I would do, if you can do this, I say it this way because it means you can't use COMMAND+Z to go back, what happens if you restart XCode and restart the simulator

Comment: Yep, look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608943/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-doing "pod install". It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try deintegrate the pods in your project and start over.
https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate