# How to use pod installed frameworks in custom swift framework?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, frameworks, cocoapods

I have built a custom swift framework with the way described on this [blog](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial) and trying to use it in swift project.

My framework used pod for third party libraries (Alamofire, APAddressBook, etc).

Successfully built framework but getting  crashes when I use in App.

This is the crash log.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/APAddressBook.framework/APAddressBook
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C878FECA-D2B5-4E92-B270-AC9668EF3A59/Demo.app/Frameworks/DemoSDK.framework/DemoSDK
>   Reason: image not found

I've tried to google to find the solution and found this similar [question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126835/swift-framework-depending-on-cocoa-pod).

As Pasta's answer, I added the Copy the Files on my framework project's build phase and added pod installed frameworks there. When I tried again to build framework and use in app, above crash log has gone but another crash happened.

Some similar answers are on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta). But my question is a bit different with it. Please read above again. I've already fixed the Image not found issue. Now facing the "required code signature missing" for pod installed frameworks.

This is new crash log.

d

> yld: Library not loaded: @rpath/APAddressBook.framework/APAddressBook 
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A925B72C-4050-4838-8819-BC7809606ABF/Demo.app/Frameworks/DemoSDK.framework/DemoSDK
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: 
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A925B72C-4050-4838-8819-BC7809606ABF/Demo.app/Frameworks/DemoSDK.framework/Frameworks/APAddressBook.framework/APAddressBook:
>   required code signature missing for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A925B72C-4050-4838-8819-BC7809606ABF/Demo.app/Frameworks/DemoSDK.framework/Frameworks/APAddressBook.framework/APAddressBook'

Comment: This error in the real device or simulator ? I gues, If it's real device, probably error's reason is distribution certificate.

Comment: Works fine in simulator. Error is in the real device only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)

Comment: @NazmulHasan, this is different issue.

Comment: @gstream79 how it  is deference `Reason: no suitable image found` and `required code signature missing for ` ? by the by try with that answer and let me

Comment: @NazmulHasan, as my question, I've already fixed the Image not found crash issue from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126835/swift-framework-depending-on-cocoa-pod). My question is code signature missing error for pod installed frameworks.

Comment: @gstream79 you have to enable `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` option under `Build Options`.

Comment: I got a same issue. It's certificate error. You create certificate again from scratch.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ, so you fixed it with new certificate use ?
Should I use same certificate for Framework and App ?

Comment: Yes I fixed it. Also you check your xcode accounts.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYILMAZ, I fixed this issue. Create certificate again from scratch and sign all frameworks on app side with script. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.